# Remove text from qt progress bar

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.4

How can I remove the text (i.e. `24%`) from the progress bar? I only want to show a plain progress bar without any text. Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve with `setTextVisible()` method, just set `false`. For example:

```
QProgressBar *pr = new QProgressBar;
pr->setValue(50);
pr->setTextVisible(false);
```